# XML image switching

Tags: xml, android-studio, imageview

I'm new to coding and I'm working on a text adventure and want the imageview to change images based on the location, I was wondering how it'd work and why this solution doesn't. Would it be better to do it based on player position? Where can I look to find information on that as I'm having some trouble.
Thanks

````
<room>
        <east>1</east>
        <description>Room 1(0)</description>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bedroom"
            />
    </room>
    <room>
        <east>2</east>
        <west>0</west>
        <description>Room 2(1)</description>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePlace1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/living"
            />
    </room>
    <room>
        <west>1</west>
        <description>Room 3(2)</description>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePlace2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen"
            />
    </room>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be nice if you use only 1 imageview and change the image based on location

to change the image use following java code:

```
imageview_object.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

make sure that your image is inside `res/drawable` folder

And to get location in latitude and logitude you can follow this link https://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

Comment: Hey, it is in one imageview, but I suppose going about it in xml like this was the wrong way? Since it wont even show 1 image.

The location is as you see in the xml file, the starting room is 0 and going east is room 1, east again is room 2 while west is back to room 0 etc.

Comment: well if you are using only one imageview then first set the default image you want to view to the user and then as per the user changes the room use the java code i have given to change the image respective to the room.